# Grails how to prevent save class with empty values

Tags: http, grails, grails-orm

I have a parent class that have a children class with no required fields. The save form has the inputs for the parent and children class.

The problem is: submit is saving children class with all null fields when I dont fill any of then.

*Question:* How do I prevent that and save no children?

- **Example:**

***Classes:***

```
class Parent {

    String name
    static hasOne = [children:Children]
    
}

class Children {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [parent : Parent]
    
    static constraints = {
        name nullable: true
    }
}
```

***HTML (.gsp):***

```
<form controller="parent" action="save" method="post">

    Parent Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" value="parent name" />

    Children Name:
    <input type="text" name="children.name" />
    
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />

</form>
```

***Relational Tables:***

```
Parent(id, name)
Children(id, name, parent_id)
```

***Controller:***

```
def save(Parent parent) {
   parent.save()
}
```

- **Submit and Save:**

***Form data sended:***

```
name: 'parent name'
children.name: ''
```

***Persisted values:***

```
Parent(1, 'parent name')
Children(1, null, 1)
```

-----------------

**What I want is:** The save method (controller) to receive the Parent class without a Children when the children have all null fields. Or another clean alternative that makes me save only the Parent class (no "empty" children).

PS: I try to solve with "@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)" at the children's name, but it didn't work

Comment: No blanks? - https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/blank.html

Comment: Separate from the `blank` constraint that @MikeW mentioned, the default behavior is the data binder will convert empty strings to `null`.  If that is not the behavior you want, setting `grails.databinding.convertEmptyStringsToNull` to false will affect that.

Comment: How is the `Parent` instance being created and populated?

Comment: I don't want to save empty strings either. I just don't want to save this Children when it's not filled. The Parent is created by grails. I receive the Parent object as argument to the save controller